# Change default printer on Windows 11 [delphi] [windows-11] [printing]

Tags: delphi, printing, windows-11

How can I change the default printer on Windows 11? The following code works fine on Windows 10 but not on Windows 11:

```
procedure TForm1.SetDefaultPrinter(NewDefPrinter: string);
var
  ResStr: array [0 .. 255] of char;
begin
  StrPCopy(ResStr, NewDefPrinter);
  WriteProfileString('windows', 'device', ResStr);
  StrCopy(ResStr, 'windows');
   SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, LongInt(@ResStr));
end;
```

Printer preferences ‘Let Windows manage my default printer‘ is off and one printer set as default.
I'm happy about any hint.

Answer (score 3):

As i see you use "old style" code. I think Microsoft already breaks capability with "WIN.INI"-file directly delivered from Win9X. Try to use generic WinApi solution for it. This should help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setdefaultprinter

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, This code works for me:

```
procedure TForm1.SetDefaultPrinter(Name: string);
  var
    fnSetDefaultPrinter: function(pszPrinter: PChar): Bool; stdcall;
    H: THandle;
    Size, Dummy: Cardinal;
    PrinterInfo: PPrinterInfo2;
begin
   if (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and (Win32MajorVersion >= 5) then begin
     @fnSetDefaultPrinter := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(winspl), 'SetDefaultPrinterW');
     if (@fnSetDefaultPrinter = NIL) then
       RaiseLastOSError;
     if NOT fnSetDefaultPrinter(PChar(Name)) then
       RaiseLastOSError;
   end
   else begin
     if NOT OpenPrinter(PChar(Name), H, NIL) then
       RaiseLastOSError;
     try
       GetPrinter(H, 2, NIL, 0, @Size);
       if GetLastError <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
         RaiseLastOSError;
       GetMem(PrinterInfo, Size);
       try
         if NOT GetPrinter(H, 2, PrinterInfo, Size, @Dummy) then
           RaiseLastOSError;
         PrinterInfo^.Attributes := PrinterInfo^.Attributes or PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT;
         if NOT Winspool.SetPrinter(H, 2, PrinterInfo, PRINTER_CONTROL_SET_STATUS) then
           RaiseLastOSError;
       finally
         FreeMem(PrinterInfo);
       end;
     finally
       ClosePrinter(H);
     end;
   end;
end;
```